# Ruby: How to make one DB:migrate dependent to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, facebook

I currently have to db migrates in my project. One of them handles all the user info and displays it on a web page. the other is used to log users in via Facebook. I'm trying to make it only create the note database for a certain Facebook user id.

So another words if i log into Facebook i should only see my database note.

here is what i have now.

in migrate folder

```
Class CreateNotes < ActiveRecord:migration
def change
   create table :notes do |t|
   t.string :notebook
   t.string :string
   t.string  :title
   t.string  :string
   t.text    :text
   t. timestamps
  end
  end
end

Class CreateUsers < ActivateRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :provider
    t.string :uid
    t.string :name
    t.string :oauth_token
    t.datetime :oauth_expires_at

    t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

Thanks for any feed back

Comment: Database migrations are for creating and maintaining your application's database schema, not for controlling behavior in the application.  They certainly don't display anything on pages.  Does what you have work right now?  The syntax doesn't look like it does.

Comment: It seems more like you want a `note` to `belong_to` a `user` rather than controlling migrations.